# can we have two error modes in pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Can i join warning as well as error for `pdo's` using set attribute

right now i have this line

```
setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION | PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
```

and i am getting warning

> Warning: PDO::setAttribute()
>   [pdo.setattribute]: SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: invalid error mode in
>   C:\wamp\www\PDO\MyPDO.php
>   on line 18

if i remove the `| PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` it works great but i like to c warnings as well. is it allowed in pdo or there is some other way ? .

Comment: I don't think so. And what sense would it make - do you want a warning *and* an exception to be thrown?

Comment: Thanks Pekka i just thought its good to get warning as well. so i thought of combining them but no problem i am fine with exceptions. cheers

Comment: you can choose from 3 error reporting methods in PDO (none, warning, exception) except for the connection call, there will always be an exception thrown. and as Pekka said, it doesn’t make sense to use warnings and exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do this, you could write a function that you call whenever you catch `PDOException` that calls `trigger_error()`, but you'll need to call it in each catch block yourself.

```
// Issue a notice/warning/whatever from a PDOException error message
function my_pdoerror($PDOException) {
   trigger_error($PDOException->getMessage(), E_USER_NOTICE);
}

try {
  // something with PDO
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
   // Call this in your catch blocks.
   my_pdoerror($e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i will not do this i read some thing on the PHP manual it was a post about the connection exception that some times pdo doesn't show exception and error so if you turn the warning on there you will see pdo warning you about the possible wrong code attempt.